# Requesting AutoFill plugin for domain

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to use the AutoFill Plugin to easily populate profile form fields from LinkedIn profiles into a website I have created that uses registration forms, and for users to enter a profile. I would like to use your AutoFill Plugin to offer users to fill this profile with their LinkedIn profile. In reading your documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/autofill-plugin

It says "domains must be allowlisted for LinkedIn AutoFill to properly function. Contact your LinkedIn representative for more information."

CanI ask to add the following domains to this allowlist?

The site is question is **https://go-digital-platform.thisiscrowdlab.com/**

Is it possible to also add a local dev URL **http://events.local** (only if possible, as the above one is more important).

Or do let me know who I should contact to add domains to the allowlist for this plugin.

Many thanks,

Comment: Whose AutoFill Plugin? StackOverflow does not release software. If someone is directing you to SO as if it's a helpdesk for them, they probably shouldn't be....

Comment: It is a LinkedIn requirement, which says:  "Your domains must be allowlisted for LinkedIn AutoFill to properly function. Contact your LinkedIn representative for more information."

Comment: And has your LinkedIn representative told you they take helpdesk style requests on Stack Overflow? Because that would be weird if so, and off-topic: see upon hovering over the `linkedin` tag that it says `Do not ask questions about LinkedIn's terms of service, problems with registering for a service with them, or what APIs they will be offering in the future. They are not appropriate for asking on Stack Overflow, *even if* LinkedIn appeared to direct you here.`

Comment: Yes it is weird. This is what they said:

In an effort to boost support for our developer community, we moved our online support forum from the Developers site to StackOverflow.
Before asking LinkedIn API-related questions at StackOverflow, be sure to: Tag question with the #linkedin hashtag so LinkedIn engineers will see them.

Remember that StackOverflow is for technical questions and answers. For general questions about LinkedIn, please use the LinkedIn Help Center.

You will have to reach out to StackOverflow and put this query with the #LinkedIn.